# How do online port checkers work?

Tags: sockets, network-programming

For example http://www.utorrent.com/testport?port=12345

How does this work? Can the server side script attempt to open a socket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways of accomplishing this through server-side scripting. As @Oded mentioned, most server-side handlers are capable of initiating socket connections on arbitrary ports, and most of those even have dedicated port-scanning packages/libraries (PHP has [**one**](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_Portscan) in the PEAR repository, Python's 'socket' module makes this type of tasks a breeze, etc...)

Keep in mind that on shared host platforms, socket connections are typically disabled for security purposes.

Another way that is also very easy to accomplish is to use a command-line port-scanner such as nmap from your server-side script. i.e in PHP, you would do echo ``nmap -p $port $ip`\`

Answer (score 1):

The server side script will try to open a connection on the specified port to the originating IP.

If there is no response (the attempt will timeout), this would be an indication that the port is not open.

Answer (score 0):

The server can try, as @Oded said.  But that doesn't ensure the receiver will respond.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, something like this happens:

- The URL request contains instructions about which port to access. The headers that your browser sends include information about where the request is originating from.
- Before responding to the request, the server tries to open a port and checks if this is successful. It waits a while before timing out.
- The webpage is rendered dynamically based on the results of this test.
- The response is returned to you containing the results.

Sometimes steps (2) and (3) will be replaced with an AJAX callback, which allows the response to return sooner.